# How to disable middle mouse click paste in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, configuration

I have recently updated from version 2016.2 to 2017.1. Not counting this issue, it looks like all settings and plugins were imported from previous version successfully.

My question is, how to disable this behavior under Linux? I have already bound functionality to my middle button in IDEA, but it is being overwritten by that stupid second clipboard paste which I don't even use.

Only related thing I found in settings was *Paste on middle mouse click* in *Terminal*. It did not change anything in the normal main editor pane.

Edit: Few months later and it is still not fixed in current IDEA version. I am paying for the IDE and this feels like being ripped off.

Answer (score 28):

1. Go to Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions.
2. Right click 'Paste from X clipboard'.
3. Select 'Remove Button2 Click'.
4. Apply.

Comment: Thanks, this was the simplest of the instructions given and did the job!

Comment: Thanks. And after removing paste action it's also handy to use "Middleclick" action to "Go to declaration or usages". So you middle click on class and see the usages

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me: Go to Settings -> Keymap and select 'Default' from the 'Keymaps:' dropdown in the top left - Or at least select away from 'Default for XWin Copy'. Then remove 'Button2 Click' from 'Paste from X clipboard.'

This is a bit of a pain because it resets all your keymaps, but at least it fixes middle click.

Comment: Actually it is not needed to select `Default` from keymap. It works as long as `Button 2 click` is removed from `Paste from X clipboard` key mapping.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-168643](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168643) 2017 EAP - Middle mouse click always pastes

Comment: This is fixed in builds 172.894, 171.4100 (June, 14 '17)